how to highlight a column header column if the column contains a data or fill color?
I have an excel sheets with more than 100 columns and over 500000 rows.
I would like to highlight a column header if the same column contains a data of a string (like empty or white space or null) or has a fill color (cell is yellow)?
Currently:
I use the conditional formatting that highlight a cell containing one white space.... the result will show some cells filled with yellow color that satisfy the condition (one white space)  and then I add filter to all the columns. I then check every column if it contains yellow colored cell.
I repeat this process many time for every new excel sheets.
Is there a better way to do it?

When you say a cell has one white space, do you mean it only has a white space or would a cell with this text (which contains a white space) be included? FOr coloured cells, how are they coloured? with conditional fomating? It might also be useful to know what your end goal is -- i.e. what do you do with the cells you have found?

I meant only a white space and no other values.
the conditional formating contains rules like
Cell Value = ' '     and format (fill) it with yellow color
this rule works... the problem is if there is one cell with color ... in the middle of 500,000  rows.... it will be difficult to scroll  down and search for it or filter and search every columns.

Did you use one of my solutions? if so which one.

Options

If you want a summary of the null cells you can use power query in excel. if you are unfamiliar with power query check some other posts: demo power query and web scrape demo. When you are in power query click "Advanced Editor" replace code with the below.

let
    n = {null, "Unanswered", "N/A"},
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Your_table_Name_here"]}[Content],
    Result = Table.FromColumns( 
      {
        Table.ColumnNames( Source ), 
        List.Transform( Table.ToColumns( Source ), each List.Count( List.Select( _, (v) => List.Contains( n, v))) ) 
      }
    )
in
    Result


You can use python in excel I don't have a demo.
How about you do a =countblank(B3:B500000) on row 2 then do conditional format for B1 would be a function of =$B$2>0.

